# How to trigger the ajax onload/success event for bootstrap3 dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap dialog taking data from remote location, it work fine. I want to execute some js code after the content had been loaded (by ajax).
I try

```
.on('shown.bs.modal', function...
```

but this is triggered immediately after modal is shown, and before content are loaded.
Thank in advance

Update:

this is the link to display the modal

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalX" class="" href="path/to/data.html">
    some text
</a>
```

this is the empty modal (before the ajax call to load content from "path/to/data.html"

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalX" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
      <div class="modal-body">
          Cargando ... / Loading ...
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

js event code...

```
$('#modalX').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    //not good to use in on ajax load :(
})
```

Comment: I think I know what the problem is but I need to see the modal initialisation code and any other code you think might help

Comment: look at my update please...

Comment: Hey, look at the update below. Bootstrap now has loaded event for modals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there is this issue with the bootstrap guys refusing to provide an `onload` or `loaded` event upon data being loaded with the remote option.

So the way around this is as follows:

Create a custom/basic anchor tag to trigger the Modal open

```
<a class="open-modal">
    Open Modal
</a>
```

Your Modal container

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalX" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    ......
    ......
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', '.open-modal', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modalX').modal({
            show: true,
            ....
        })
        .load('path/to/data.html', function(e){
            alert(e); // where e is the content
            // do what it is you need to do in here
        });
    });
});
```

### Update

The Bootstrap guys seem to have finally agreed to add the [loaded](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10911) event to the modal component in version [3.1.0](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Now you can do ..

```
$('#modalX').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

Comment: uhmm, that's what i was affraid(the attitude of the bootstrap guys). OK, i will try your suggestion. Tx